# If Any *.File Exists, Delete All *.File

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'm using visual c# in a winforms application. I want to check and see if `*.plr` exists, delete *all* files with the extension `.plr`. I am confused because the following code doesn't work for some reason.

```
if (File.Exists("*.plr"))
{
    File.Delete("*.plr");
}
```

Comment: i thought in C# you had to specify directory first.. then get `FileInfo` instances from it..

Comment: @BagusTesa I have changed the directory. I just didn't include it in the post.

Comment: "Doesn't work" how?  Do you get an error?  Does it not delete the file(s)?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: @Tim It just didn't delete the file, look at un-lucky's post for the solution

Comment: When you read documentation on [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where did you find support for wildcards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to get all files with specified extension from the Directory in which you have to perform this action. `.GetFiles()` method under the `Directory` class will help you to get all files with a specific extension(use `SearchOption` if you need to check subdirectories as well). Then iterate those files and delete one by one. Hope that this will do that job for you:

```
string dirPath = "path of Directory";
Directory.GetFiles(dirPath , "*.plr", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
         .ForEach(x => System.IO.File.Delete(x));
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly :)

Comment: @TannerH.: Glad to hear that. Happy to help you